# Service worker cannot accept double scope

Tags: vue.js, parameters, service-worker

I have a service worker in my webapp (vuejs, laravel) is initialise like that (welcome.blade.php):

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
                window.addEventListener('load', function(){
                    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js').then(function(){
                        console.log('Service worker load');
                    })
                })
            }
```

Is work fine but now i want to pass a params in my vue-router exemple http://localhost:8000/panier/250.

For panier(http://localhost:8000/panier) is work fine but if i pass a second scope(250) is crash with two errors :

```
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8000/panier/') with script ('http://localhost:8000/panier/service-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

So i try do not pass params i juste do that http://localhost:8000/panier/test but is crash two.

I think is really don't want the two scope but i want it =/. I don't found really similar problem where is crash for two scope.

Big thanks for everyone help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js')`.
What is actually happening is that for every route you go to, the browser is trying to fetch `service-worker.js` file from there. So if you go to `http://localhost:8000/panier`, the browser fetches the service worker file from the same directory as `panier` which is the root and gets it perfectly but when you go one level deeper it cannot find the file. What you should do is change
`navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js')` to

`navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')` or just `navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')`.

Comment: With '/service-worker.js' i have no errors so thanks you !